# How to copy a binary string to and from a structure, in C.

Tags: c, struct, binary

I have an executable file that is a little robot that is supposed to follow a line and my job is to make the C code to command it. My problem here is getting the data from the robot program itself and sending it back.

The instructions are passed back and fourth to the software with an 8 bits binary code and I have these two structures to handle the data.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned speed:4;
    unsigned inv_right_wheel:1;
    unsigned right_wheel:1;
    unsigned inv_left_wheel:1;
    unsigned left_wheel:1;
} INPUT;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char unused:2;
    unsigned char capt_left:1;
    unsigned char capt_right:1;
    unsigned char cont_back_right:1;
    unsigned char cont_front_right:1;
    unsigned char cont_back_left:1;
    unsigned char cont_front_left:1;
} OUTPUT;
```

To find where the address of the binary code is located I have a little function like this `REGISTER(0xE001)` (its type is a `static volatile unsigned char * REGISTER(unsigned short address)`) which returns the address where to look.

My main looks like this:

```
int main() { 
    OUTPUT  *out;
    INPUT   *in;

    out = REGISTER(0xE001);


    printf("%d", out.capt_left);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work?  That code won't even compile - `out` is a pointer, so at the very least you need `out->capt_left`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "cannot get anything to work" part? Does the code compile? Do you get errors compiling? What do you see under the debugger if it runs?

Comment: Editorial note: using bitfields may end in tears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded fun.  If you want the robot to communicate back to you, it must have some sort of API or register it uses.  Right now, system register 0xE001 is where it is telling you about output.  If this register is Read/Writable, you can do:

```
out->capt_left = 1;
```

If you communicate through INPUT (logical to think so), you need to find where the INPUT register lives.  This will be in your documentation somewhere.  and you would do:

```
in = (REGISTER(0xE000));   // Guessing on Register location.
in->speed = 1;
...
```

Does this give you an idea of where to start?  BTW, there is a strong chance that you want to write entire bytes at a time to the input such that:

```
INPUT buffer;

buffer.speed = 1;
buffer.inv_right_wheel = 0;
...

*in = buffer;
```

or even:

```
*(REGISTER(INPUT_REGISTER)) = 0x4F;  // Speed to 4, all other bits set true - maybe depending on bitfield order!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @MattPhillips.  I've done similiar stuff in the past so I think I knew where he was coming from :)